# Prevent line break after html element

Tags: html, css, formatting

I have a large paragraph that has a span element in it (a few, but one here for simplification). I want to force this span element to be on the same line as the text that comes after it (since it's an introduction to that text). How can I prevent a line break between this element and the text after it (how to keep these two together), but keep it as display: inline-block?

I tried to use nbsp, but it didn't work, and using whitespace: nowrap would prevent the rest of the text from wrapping.

```css
span#outerSpan {
  width: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  /* if you delete this and the float, it works, but I need it to be floated right and not take up space*/
  float: right;
}

div#box {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 140px;
  white-space: normal;
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">aaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaaa a <span id="outerSpan"><span id="innerSpan">p</span></span>bb bbbbbbbbb bbbbbbb bbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbb bbbbbb bbbb</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The inline-block display doenst work with a float.
**"inline-block is ignored due to the float. If 'float' has a value other than 'none', the box is floated and 'display' is treated as 'block'"** (copied from my vscode)

Also why do you need the float? float is an quite old standard, maybe you can use something newer to achieve the same?
Maybe if you tell me what you're trying to make, I can provide a better way to do that :)

**Edit after Comments:**

Maybe you can consider the following:

```css
  .textBox{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    width: fit-content;
  }
  p{
    position: relative;
  }
  p .note{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(calc(100% + 10px));
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="textBox">
    <p><span class="note">This is my note</span>This is my Text</p>
    <p>This is another line in my intro text</p>
    <p><span class="note">This is a Note</span>And this is my final Line in the intro text</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here you have a p Element for each new line and a .note Element in the p Tag if needed. The span is then transformed to the right.
This is also not the best to do, since it can cause side issues for other Content or responsive Design. Maybe I can look into that later.

Does that solution fit for you?

Comment: Ah, that makes sense (still doesn't work with float though).  However, if I get rid of the float and try to move it to the side a different way, the inline-block is still a problem, and if I try to use position: absolute to make it not take up space, it still goes to the row above.

Also, I'm trying to get that text to be on the right side of the box but not take up space in the box itself (ex: for notes or something similar). This works, but not if it's the span is at the edge.

Comment: So if i get this right, you want to have a "note" in some type of "sidebar" of your Textbox?

Comment: Yes, and I want that note element to be right before the text that it's for In the HTML, but be shown in that sidebar (preferably with CSS).

Comment: I edited my answer, take a look :)

Comment: That doesn't work (besides for the fact that p tags are block, it also doesn't connect to the next text element).

Comment: Okay well then i didnt quite get what you want. I thought this look is what you wanned to achieve?  Maybe you can explain a bit moe? or add E.g. an Image of the desired look to your question?